# swapping child elements of div using javascript by drag and drop

Tags: javascript, dom, html

I tried swapping two elements inside  div1 and div2 tag but only the first replace function executes properly the other element is not swapped

- either one of the div is getting swapped at once but when i try to swap both at same time it doesn't happen please help me out 
  *

  ```
  <head>
      <style type="text/css">
          #div1 {
              width:350px;
              height:70px;
              padding:10px;
              border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
          }
          #div2 {
              width:350px;
              height:70px;
              padding:10px;
              border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
          }
      </style>
      <script>
          function allowDrop(ev) {
              ev.preventDefault();
          }

          function drag(ev) {
              var child = ev.target;
              var parents = child.parentNode;
              ev.dataTransfer.setData("child1", child.id);
              ev.dataTransfer.setData("parent1", parents.id);
          }

          function drop(ev) {
              ev.preventDefault();
              var childid1 = ev.dataTransfer.getData("child1");
              var parentid1 = ev.dataTransfer.getData("parent1");
              var parent1 = document.getElementById(parentid1);
              var c = ev.currentTarget.childNodes;
              var childid2 = c[1].id;
              parent1.replaceChild(c[1], document.getElementById(childid1));
              var parent2 = ev.currentTarget;
              parent2.removeChild(c[1]);
              parent2.appendChild(document.getElementById(childid1));
          }
      </script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          <img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          <img id="drag2" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="236" height="49">
      </div>
  </body>
  ```

Answer (score 8):

I think your fundamental flaw is that you do not cater for the fact that when you do your first `replaceChild`, the image you are inserting is removed from its parent so it is no longer there to replace with the second image.

I found your variable names somewhat confusing, and have rewritten your code in a simpler fashion as follows:

```
function allowDrop (ev) {
   ev.preventDefault ();
}

function drag (ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData ("src", ev.target.id);
}

function drop (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault ();
  var src = document.getElementById (ev.dataTransfer.getData ("src"));
  var srcParent = src.parentNode;
  var tgt = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;

  ev.currentTarget.replaceChild (src, tgt);
  srcParent.appendChild (tgt);
}
```

You can test this code at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jstoolsmith/TJKmh/)