# How to drag and drop a draggable element and swap its place with another element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created six `div` elements, each with an `id`. Inside these six `div` elements, I created six `img` elements, each with an `id`.

Now I want to drag any image and drop it over any of the six `div` elements.

When I drag image 1 and drop it over `div` 5, then the `div` 5 image should move to `div` 1. How can I achieve this? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <interface id="interface">
        <div id="div1"><img src="images/images/Number1.png" alt="one" id="drag1" draggable="true"></div>
        <div id="div2"><img src="images/images/Number2.png" alt="two" id="drag2" draggable="true"></div>
        <div id="div3"><img src="images/images/Number3.png" alt="three" id="drag3" draggable="true"></div>
        <div id="div4"><img src="images/images/Number4.png" alt="four" id="drag4" draggable="true"></div>
        <div id="div5"><img src="images/images/Number5.png" alt="five" id="drag5" draggable="true"></div>
        <div id="div6"><img src="images/images/Number6.png" alt="six" id="drag6" draggable="true"></div>
    </interface>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript code starts here:

```
console.log("Get Started");

const imgboxes = document.querySelectorAll("img");
console.log(imgboxes);
const divBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("div");
console.log(divBoxes);

for (imgbox of imgboxes) {
  imgbox.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => {
    console.log("dragStart triggred");
    setTimeout(() => {
      e.target.className = "hide";
    }, 0);
    
  })
}
for (imgbox of imgboxes) {
  imgbox.addEventListener('dragend', (e) => {
    console.log("dragEnd triggred");
    e.target.className = "imgbox"
  })
}

for (divbox of divBoxes) {
  divbox.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
    console.log("dragOver triggred");
    e.preventDefault();
    
  })

  divbox.addEventListener('dragenter', () => {
    console.log("dragEnter triggred");
  })
  divbox.addEventListener('dragleave', () => {
    console.log("dragLeave triggred");
  })
  divbox.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
    console.log("dragDrop triggred");
    e.target.appendChild(imgbox);
  })

}
```

CSS code is here:

```
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4, #div5, #div6{
    float: left;
    width:85px;
    height:85px;
    margin: 20px; 
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #drag1, #drag2, #drag3, #drag4, #drag5, #drag6{
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    margin-top: 2px;
  }
  #interface{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 100px auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .hide{
    display: none;
  }
  .imgbox{
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    margin-top: 2px;
  }
```

Comment: Why not use an external library. I recently answer something which involved sortable.js library. Seemed pretty easy https://stackoverflow.com/a/73094106/3807365

Answer (score 1):

Based on [swapping child elements of div using JavaScript by drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16785413/18595321), here is a demo.

The `event.target.id` is stored within the `dragStart()` function.

This dragged image `id` can then be retrieved in the `drop()` function.

Then that `id` can be used to retrieve the `draggedImage`.

Within `drop()`, we can test to make sure that the image is not being dropped back into the same container.

`appendChild()` removes the child element being appended from its previous parent.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
const containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");

images.forEach((image) => {
  image.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
  image.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd);
});

containers.forEach((container) => {
  container.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver);
  container.addEventListener("drop", drop);
});

function dragStart(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("draggedImageId", event.target.id);
  setTimeout(() => event.target.classList.toggle("hidden"));
}

function dragEnd(event) {
  event.target.classList.toggle("hidden");
}

function dragOver(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function drop(event) {
  const draggedImageId = event.dataTransfer.getData("draggedImageId");
  const draggedImage = document.getElementById(draggedImageId);
  const fromContainer = draggedImage.parentNode;
  const toContainer = event.currentTarget;

  if (toContainer !== fromContainer) {
    fromContainer.appendChild(toContainer.firstElementChild);
    toContainer.appendChild(draggedImage);
  }
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: solid 2px black;
  background: pink;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: solid 2px black;
  background: white;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <img id="drag1" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80/?cat" draggable="true" />
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img id="drag2" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80/?fruit" draggable="true" />
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img id="drag3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80/?car" draggable="true" />
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img id="drag4" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/80x80/?dog" draggable="true" />
  </div>
</div>
```