# Drag and drop cells on CSS Grid only works properly when moving a cell to the right, and does not work when moving a cell to the left

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, css-grid

I have a CSS Grid and I'm trying to implement a drag and drop (or drag and swap) feature. It's getting close to working as desired but as the title says, the dragged cell will not drop properly into a cell to the left of its original position. The feature only works when the cell being dragged is moved to the right. Can anyone see what the problem is?

```js
var dragSrcEl = null;
function handleDragStart(e) {
  this.style.opacity = "0.4";
  dragSrcEl = this;
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
  return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
    this.classList.add("over");
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
  this.classList.remove("over");
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  if (dragSrcEl != this) {
    this.replaceWith(this, dragSrcEl);
  }
  return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
  this.style.opacity = "1";
  items.forEach(function (item) {
    item.classList.remove("over");
  });
}
  let items = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-container .grid-item");
  items.forEach(function (item) {
    item.addEventListener("dragstart", handleDragStart, false);
    item.addEventListener("dragenter", handleDragEnter, false);
    item.addEventListener("dragover", handleDragOver, false);
    item.addEventListener("dragleave", handleDragLeave, false);
    item.addEventListener("drop", handleDrop, false);
    item.addEventListener("dragend", handleDragEnd, false);
  });
```

```css
.grid-container {
       display: grid;
       grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 40px);
       grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 30px);
       margin: auto;
     }
        .grid-item {
          border: 1px solid #666;
          background-color: #ddd;
          cursor: move;
        }
          .grid-item.over {
            border: 3px dotted #666;
          }

          [draggable] {
            user-select: none;
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container" id="grid">
  <div draggable="true" class="grid-item" id="box1">1</div>
  <div draggable="true" class="grid-item" id="box2">2</div>
  <div draggable="true" class="grid-item" id="box3">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have added six more grid items to your code, so in my sample code the grid is three by three.

Now, when you drag a grid item, you can clearly see that no swapping is taking place in either direction. For example, drag item 9 and drop it on 2. The new order will be:

```
1 2 9  3 4 5  6 7 8  and not  1 9 3  4 5 6  7 8 2  as expected if swapping took place
```

Your code is inserting the dragged item to a new position and shuffling the rest of the items.

Please have a look at the answer to the following question for a [drag and drop swap implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73119729/how-to-drag-and-drop-a-draggable-element-and-swap-its-place-with-another-element)

```js
var dragSrcEl = null;

function handleDragStart(e) {
  this.style.opacity = "0.4";
  dragSrcEl = this;
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
  return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
  this.classList.add("over");
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
  this.classList.remove("over");
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  if (dragSrcEl != this) {
    this.replaceWith(this, dragSrcEl);
  }
  return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
  this.style.opacity = "1";
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.remove("over");
  });
}
let items = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-container .grid-item");
items.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("dragstart", handleDragStart, false);
  item.addEventListener("dragenter", handleDragEnter, false);
  item.addEventListener("dragover", handleDragOver, false);
  item.addEventListener("dragleave", handleDragLeave, false);
  item.addEventListener("drop", handleDrop, false);
  item.addEventListener("dragend", handleDragEnd, false);
});
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 40px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 30px);
  margin: auto;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  background-color: #ddd;
  cursor: move;
}

.grid-item.over {
  border: 3px dotted #666;
}

[draggable] {
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

  <body>
    <div class="grid-container" id="grid">
      <div draggable="true" class="grid-item" id="box1">1</div>
      <div draggable="true" class="grid-item" id="box2">2</div>
      <div draggable="true" class="grid-item" id="box3">3</div>
      <div draggable="true" class="grid-item" id="box4">4</div>
      <div draggable="true" class="grid-item" id="box5">5</div>
      <div draggable="true" class="grid-item" id="box6">6</div>
      <div draggable="true" class="grid-item" id="box7">7</div>
      <div draggable="true" class="grid-item" id="box8">8</div>
      <div draggable="true" class="grid-item" id="box9">9</div>
    </div>
```